# I have problem with the date picker with table?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<td class="col-50 text-right">                   
@Html.ngTextBox(ControlType.Date, true, "txtExpDate", null, new { @ng_model = "PharmacyStockInDetail.ExpDate", @class = "form-control", @data_smart_datepicker = "", @data_date_format = "{{Format.SmartDatePicker}}", @placeholder = "ExpDate" })
</td>
```

the date picker is not loading can I get help??

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help fix your problem.

Comment: how can I add the date picker in the column of the table? <td> i  want to load the date picker </td> of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is clear.
Try this code. This will serve the purpose.You will have to edit it according your requirement though.

**You can see the demo [here](https://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/demo-add-jquery-datepicker-inside-ng-repeat-directive.htm)**

And also, If you miss any library import, you will not get the datepicker.Please check whether you have imported the necessary libraries correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Set focus on the last column cells to select date!</p>

    <div ng-app="myApp" 
        ng-controller="myController">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name of the Book</th>
                        <th>Issuing Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="books in booksArray | orderBy : 'values.id'">

                <td>{{books.values.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{books.values.name}}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" datepicker ng-model="datevalue" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // CREATE THE books OBJECT.
        $scope.books = [
            { 'id': '1', 'name': 'jQuery' },
            { 'id': '2', 'name': 'CSS3' },
            { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Angular 2' }
        ]

        $scope.booksArray = Object.keys($scope.books)
            .map(function (value, index) {
                return { values: $scope.books[value] }
            }
        );
    } ]);

    myApp.directive("datepicker", function () {

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            });
        }

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
<td class="col-50 text-right">
    <input [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
</td>
```

This information was taken from the [Angular docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ngTextBox(ControlType.Date, false, "txtExpDate", null, new { @ng_model = "Detail.ExpDate", @class = "form-control", @data_smart_datepicker = "", @data_date_format = "{{Format.SmartDatePicker}}", @placeholder = "Date" })
```

The above Code is Worked  ...!
Am using dynamic tag builder that why everything is in parameters